# spring boot actuator not showing the heap dump option

Tags: java, spring-boot, heap-dump

I have added the spring boot actuator jar in the existing spring boot app

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am able to see the actuator urls list but the `heapdump` option is missing

```
    {"_links":
     {
      "self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator","templated":false},
      "health":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/health","templated":false},
      "health-path":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/{*path}","templated":true},
      "info":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/info","templated":false}
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

I had also included below lines in applications.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't enabled the heap dump actuator endpoint.
Use the following for enabling it

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=threaddump
management.endpoint.threaddump.enabled=true
```

Comment: thank you  i had this in my applications.properties `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

Comment: try enabling it, management.endpoint.threaddump.enabled=true